# Get GuildMember by UserId in discord.js v13 Slash Command

Tags: discord.js

I've searched a lot of data so far, but I can't find any code that works. Can you tell me the code you get?
This is how I register Slash Command.

```js
client.api.applications(client.user.id).guilds(guild).commands.post({
  data: {
    name: command.name,
    description: command.description,
    options: command.options
  }
});
```

I'm Korean, so I wrote a translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the [`GuidMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) details of the user by the user's id, you would first have to fetch the guild id, then you can use `client.guilds.cache.get(guildid).members.cache.get(userid)`. But since you are doing this in a slash command, you would receive an [`Interaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Interaction) object when the user uses the slash command, so then you can just use `interaction.guild.members.cache.get(userid)`. If you want to get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) details of the user who ran the slash command, then you can just use `const guildmember = interaction.member`